# Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated - Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5

I just deploy my laravel

## 5.0

site to Heroku.
I believe Heroku is using PHP 7.1 by default.

I did everything, and finally got it to deployed, but I see error on my page

> Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated

---

**config/app.php**

`'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',`

[image]

I've already run `php artisan key:generate`.

**Any hints on how I prevent that ?**

Comment: Yup, [it's deprecated all right](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-iv-size.php). What's your question?

Comment: Upgrading to [Laravel 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/releases#laravel-5.1) or later might help: "In previous versions of Laravel, encryption was handled by the `mcrypt` PHP extension. However, beginning in Laravel 5.1, encryption is handled by the `openssl` extension, which is more actively maintained."

Comment: It work on my local L 5.0 on PHP 5.6. Should I update my Laravel to 5.1/5.2/5.3 ? or downgrade my PHP to 5.6 on Heroku ? Is it even possible ? Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: I always recommend using the latest version of your language and framework if possible. I'd say you should upgrade your dev box to PHP 7.1, then upgrade Laravel to 5.4, make sure everything works, and push that up to Heroku.

Comment: [`openssl_cipher_iv_length()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-cipher-iv-length.php)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Will do !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have discovered, [`mcrypt_get_iv_size()` is deprecated as of PHP 7.1](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-iv-size.php).

Upgrading to Laravel 5.1 or later should make this warning go away since it [uses `openssl` instead of `mcrypt`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/releases#laravel-5.1).

Note that Laravel 5.1 (a long-term support release) will [receive two years of bug fixes and three years of security fixes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/releases#support-policy) from [its release in July, 2016](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-1-released). Non-LTS releases receive six months of bug fixes and one year of security fixes.

I recommend upgrading your development environment to the latest version of PHP, then upgrading either to the latest release or the latest LTS release and making sure your app still works as expected.

Once you're happy, push to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me:

```
$iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC');//16
```

Or

else you can use other git repository "[defuse/php-encrption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/docs/InstallingAndVerifying.md)" for existing version to work